# SIDT instruction returns wrong base address in a Linux user-space process

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, interrupt, instructions

I made the following x86-64 program to view where the base address of the Interrupt Descriptor Tables starts:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
        uint16_t limit;
        uint64_t base;
}idt_data_t;

static inline void store_idt(idt_data_t *idt_data)
{
        asm volatile("sidt %0":"=m" (*idt_data));
}

int main(void)
{
        idt_data_t idt_data;

        store_idt(&idt_data);

        printf("IDT Limit : 0x%X\n", idt_data.limit);
        printf("IDT Base  : 0x%lX\n", idt_data.base);

        return 0;
}
```

And it prints the following:

```
IDT Limit : 0xFFF
IDT Base  : 0xFFFFFE0000000000
```

The base address doesn't seem to be correct because the address should always be a physical address, am I right?

Also, I'm not sure but the limit seems to be too high. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The limit is correct for 256 entries of 16 bytes each. The address is linear, not physical.

Comment: What OS is this?  Some might trap `sidt` and emulate it, since addresses of kernel structures are normally none of userspace's business.  E.g. Linux has code for this, https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d04f7de0a5134de13420e72ae62a26f05d312c06/arch/x86/kernel/umip.c#L65

Comment: Hi, I'm using Linux server 5.4.0-77-generic. So the kernel might emulate the sidt instruction and return something else? I tried running the same program in ring 0 and it returns the same values.

Comment: You can't run programs in ring 0, unless you mean you ported this to a kernel module?  If you mean `root` user, UID=0, that's still ring 3, so buggy programs you run as root can't crash the whole machine (except by using system calls).  e.g. you can't run an `lidt` instruction to replace the interrupt table, or `mov %rax, %cr3` to install a new page table, or any other privileged instruction.

Comment: yes, I made a kernel module and installed it with insmod. If I cant get the value of the IDT register is there any other way of doing it? I want to learn how interrupts work in the x64 architecture.

Comment: @Nicolas: In that case it probably is the correct linear address. For other ways to obtain it, there's no easy alternative (unless you want to run Linux inside an emulator so you can ask the emulator what the IDT base is).

Comment: @PeterCordes You can run programs in Ring 0 with the `iopl` system call iirc.

Comment: @fuz: no, IOPL is actually a separate hardware state from CPL. You can set IO privilege level = 0 using `iopl()`. IOPL=0 allows in/out/cli/sti with CPL>0, but not other privileged instructions like the examples I picked.  (I avoided mentioning stuff like locking up a core (and quickly the whole system when run_on blocks) by disabling interrupts, because you *can* do that from user space with `iopl`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah yes makes sense.

Comment: Just saying: `sidt` is **not** privileged unless `CR4.UMIP = 1`.  It is also relatively easy to use a specpoline to extract its result from a transient execution (if you really want to go down that road).

Answer (score 1):

It's a *linear address*, not necessarily a *physical address*.  In other words, it's subject to the page table like most other addresses.  It has to be in pages that are never paged to disk--it wouldn't be able to handle page faults if not--but it can be in addresses that differ physically from virtually.

On x86-64, each entry of the IDT is 16 bytes long.  There are 256 interrupt vectors.  256 * 16 = 4096 = 0x1000.  The IDTR limit is a "less than or equal" check, so it's typical to use 0xFFF.

`SIDT` is a privileged instruction on newer CPUs if the OS enables a certain feature, so it's advisable not to use it in user mode unless you're writing an exploit PoC or something.  It's possible that an OS lies about the answer rather than throwing an exception, but I don't know.

Comment: 64-bit mode is only possible with paging enabled, so `sidt` in 64-bit mode is definitely a virtual address.  (And that very high virtual address is certainly not also a valid physical address, although you're right that on a kernel that used a different memory layout from Linux, it could be.)